# Validate Email in Google Forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, google-forms

I am using a Google Form to collect name and email addresses for newsletter sign ups. The email address field is simply a text field in Google Forms therefore it will accept any text.

My goal is to validate the email address to ensure that an email address has been entered and not any ole text. Below is code for the Google Form. What code can I add to it in order to validate the email address field?

```
<form action="http://spreadsheets.google.com/formResponse?key=pqbhTz7PIHum_4qKEdbUWVg&amp;embedded=true" method="post" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">

<h1>Styled Google form with confirmation redirect</h1>
<div class="errorbox-good">
<div class="ss-form-entry"><label for="entry_1" class="ss-q-title">Your Name?
</label>
<label for="entry_1" class="ss-q-help"></label>
<input type="text" name="entry.1.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1"></div></div>
<br> <div class="errorbox-good">
<div class="ss-form-entry"><label for="entry_2" class="ss-q-title">Your Email?
</label>
<label for="entry_2" class="ss-q-help"></label>
<input type="text" name="entry.2.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_2"></div></div>
<br> <div class="errorbox-good">
<div class="ss-form-entry"><label for="entry_3" class="ss-q-title">How easy was this tutorial?
</label>

<label for="entry_3" class="ss-q-help"></label>
<ul class="ss-choices"><li class="ss-choice-item"><input type="radio" name="entry.3.group" value="Very easy!" class="ss-form-input" id="group_3_1">
<label class="ss-choice-label" for="group_3_1">Very easy!</label></li> <li class="ss-choice-item"><input type="radio" name="entry.3.group" value="Pretty easy" class="ss-form-input" id="group_3_2">
<label class="ss-choice-label" for="group_3_2">Pretty easy</label></li> <li class="ss-choice-item"><input type="radio" name="entry.3.group" value="Not easy" class="ss-form-input" id="group_3_3">
<label class="ss-choice-label" for="group_3_3">Not easy</label></li>
</ul></div></div>
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="pageNumber" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="backupCache" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You can also use Required Field. Add required="" in your input tag and also type = "email" for email valifation

Comment: Latest browser version provide <input type="email">. It validate email input automatically on form submit.

Comment: Thanks guys for mentioning <input type="email"> This did work for me, but it does not check for "periods" which is a bummer. Therefore it will accept an email such as bob@yahoo without the .com ----- Please let me know of any other methods!

Comment: Your question Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573488/why-does-html5-form-validation-allow-emails-without-a-dot

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link @herr This is working for me and it is so simple. But, one question, does it matter if I am using XHTML? Is is true that <input type="email"> is only valid for HTML5?

Comment: As I know it will work for XHTML but with <input type="email"/> or <input type="email" /> with end/close tag.

Comment: One more question @herr will I need server-side validation or will <input type="email"/> be enough ?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily validate email in jquery using regex as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ValidateEmail(email) {
    var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    return expr.test(email);
};
$("#btnsubmit").on("click", function () {
    if (!ValidateEmail($("#entry_2").val())) {
        alert("Invalid email address.");
        return false;
    }
    else {
         // Valid email address
    }
});

</script>
```

And assign an id to your submit button as:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id='btnsubmit' value="Submit">
```

Add Jquery reference on your form  as:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pawankullu/d0pb0eco/)

Comment: This code is not working for me. I also tested it in WordPress 2012 Theme. My Google Form continues to submit any text without displaying error. What could be the problem? Or is there an alternative method? Somebody above mentioned <input type="email"> and that worked but it is not super effective because it does not check for "periods". There must be a way?

Comment: Have you added jquery file reference ?

Comment: Yes I think, but can you post what you mean by jquery file reference - maybe I am making a mistake. Don't know why jquery is not working for me. Initially I tried a jquery validation plugin by following [this tutorial](http://morning.am/tutorials/google-forms-and-jquery-validation/) but it gave incorrect errors such as "Please enter a number greater than 0" for an email field. But a plugin seems unnecessary for a simple task, right?