# Should email validation requires the domain part contains a dot?

Tags: jquery, html, email, jquery-inputmask

I noticed that the built-in browser validation for `<input type="email" />` requires a format of `xxx@xxx`. Only the `@` character is required. There is no need to a dot, like `email@stackoverflow.com`.

It is the same with the popular jQuery.inputmask, the rule of `email` alias does not require the dot, either.

I am just curious. Is it a standard way to ignore the dot in email validation now? I haven't seen any email address on the root level domain. What is the reason to ignore the dot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does HTML5 form-validation allow emails without a dot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573488/why-does-html5-form-validation-allow-emails-without-a-dot)

Comment: emails are complicated, almost anything containing `@` could be an email, even `bill@com`, which is why validating too strict tend to lead to problems.

Comment: Thanks, Juhana. It appears to be duplicate.

Comment: [Play framework](https://playframework.com/documentation/1.4.1/api/play/data/validation/EmailCheck.html) requires a dot in the domain, unfortunately, since MS userPrincipalName (also based on RFC-822) validates without a dot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [RFC 822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt), chapter 6, gives the specification of an address in augmented Backus-Naur Form  (BNF):

```
addr-spec   =  local-part "@" domain
local-part  =  word *("." word)
domain      =  sub-domain *("." sub-domain)
```

Using this specification `a@b` is a valid address.

Comment: The spec is stupid, because every email address in real life has a .com, .net, etc.  It is a somewhat common user error to forget that ending, so in real life, following the spec means a lot of faulty email addresses get accepted.

Comment: @Acyra, the spec is not stupid at all, since `user@localhost` is a perfectly valid email, and so is something like `user@com`. An example of the second type, where a TLD can point to something is the domain `uz` as of Oct. 2018. See results for `nslookup uz` if you're curious.

Comment: I was trying to use a built-in validator in .NET and it allows user@localhost like you said.  But, I agree with Acyra, it's stupid.  That case is very rare.  So email validators that are built in to a framework should at least give you the option to require the top-level domain (maybe even default to requiring it and allow for no top level domain as an option).  In my code, I don't want to allow localhost or an IP address as the domain.