# Symfony how to validate an EmailType by not allowing emails without an ending dot something

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, email

Currently the [EmailType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/email.html) of Symfony allows any email like:

`"whatever@domain"`

So there is no validation against the domain of the email

what is the best way to make it accepts only email like:

`"whatever@domain.something"`

so that the domain should contain at least one dot.

Since it should be a common issue, I was wondering if there's already a built-in way to accomplish it.

Comment: Since you are talking about `EmailType` instead of `EmailValidator`, are you talking about the html5 client-side validation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Email` constraint to validate email values correctly:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class User 
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;
}
```

On submit the form the `EmailValidator` checks whether this `'/^.+\@\S+\.\S+$/'` pattern is valid or not, and throws a violation constraint if not.

Answer (score 3):

The HTML5 `email` type allows email such as [`example@localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples). If you want to be more stricter, you can [add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20573538/711206) the regex to the HTML5 input. You can do that when you renders the HTML widget of the `email` field:

```
{{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'pattern': '[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,63}$'}}) }}
```