# validation EmailAddress is not valid

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Is it possible to convert DataType.EmailAddress to normal email format. Not sure, but in my opinion everything worked well before.

Now:

```
    [Display(Name="E-mail")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите E-mail")] 
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

Validation will miss the e-mail without a zone.

[image]
[image]

I know I can fix it with regex. But maybe there is possibility to fix the attribute?

Comment: Also the correct address is not vb@gmail. And validation passes it

Comment: That's not true - `vb@gmail` is a *valid* email address (according to the *format* of an email address). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573488/why-does-html5-form-validation-allow-emails-without-a-dot) for more.

Comment: Email address can be without a zone (.com)?

Comment: The part after the `@` is literally the mail server's hostname. It's of course typical for that to be a standard online website like `gmail.com`, but it doesn't have to be. You might have a local mailserver at `foo`, in which case `bob@foo` might be a perfectly valid address.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're right. I would look into the eyes of that person who did this. But as they say. Complicating is simple - difficult to simplify.