# Why HTML5 pattern is not detecting wrong/correct email addresses?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor, model-view-controller

I have used this

```
       <input type="text" id="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
```

So if email address is not in valid format then it should throw error.

it is to catch wrong email address format like `name@jjjj` or name or `name@` or `name@jj.cooooo` etc

but it doesn't work i.e. it throws the message i.e. pattern must be matched even if the email is correct.

Comment: There is no `@` present in your pattern

Comment: how would I adjust that?

Comment: You could add it like `[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}`

Comment: error: "[" is not valid at the start of a code block. Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid. –

Comment: Did you try it like this? `<input type="text" id="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>`

Comment: yes, still it thorws the same error

Comment: Can you check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y3fncvzx/

Comment: yes it does but not in my Razor code

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="email">` [to get browser support](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) for checking.

Answer to why "johnny@gmail" is accepted:

> You can theoretically have an address without a "." in

See the original [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20573649/10687003)

Comment: .com is not valid email address, so it will fail the check. Or how do you mean it would not work?

Comment: see i haven't mentioned the .com in it and still it worked