# Mail address validation check

Tags: c#, email

I'm trying to parse email address to display name, address.
This is the example. `user<test@nomail.com>` => `user, test@nomail.com`

I've implemented this using `MailAddress` class,
But my problem is that if string is not valid email address, `MailAddress` throws an exception - and I do not want the exception.

I've searched many email validation method using regex but they check email only (`test@nomail.com`) but not the full address (`user<test@nomail.com>`).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why not use try-catch with MailAddress class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: I used try-catch, but there are a lot of non email data and it causes too many exception and performance problem. So i want to check before try, catch.

Comment: I've actually blogged about mail validation - [Validate mail address format the easy way – a follow up](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/04/06/validate-mail-address-format-the-easy-way-a-follow-up/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's very, very hard and complicated to write a regular expression that will conform exactly to mail address RFC standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) - and also, keep in mind the standards keeps updating.

[Microsoft's official recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-verify-that-strings-are-in-valid-email-format) used to be to use a long, unreadable, unmaintainable regular expression - however they did change that recommendation to use a simple, short regular expression that will only validate that there's a `@` and a `.` separated by at least one non-space char between them and between the start and end of the string - so an email address like `a@b.c` can pass this test.

If you're working with large amounts of strings and fear a performance penalty, go ahead and verity that the string will likely pass the `EmailAddress` constructor using the regular expression suggested in the docs, which is simple enough to read and understand - `^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+$`
(note that `a@b` [is still a valid mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20573804/3094533)....)

Then, simply attempt to create an instance of `MailAddress` in a `try...catch` block.
This will also help you parse the mail address, because [this class has properties that does a lot of the work for you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?view=netcore-3.1#properties) - you can get the Host, the User, and even the Display name (if provided, of course).

Here's a simple demo ([check it live on Rextester](https://rextester.com/GAHB3382)):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var strings = new [] {
        "user<test@nomail.com>", // valid.
        "test@nomail.com", // valid.
        "Invalid<testnomail.com>", // Invalid.
        "Invalid<test@com>", // Invalid. Note: This will return a "false positive" if only tested using MailAddress's constructor - but it's not really false.
    };
    foreach(var a in strings)
    {
        ParseMailAddress(a);
    }
}


static void ParseMailAddress(string address)
{
     Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
     Console.WriteLine("Input: {0}", address);

    if(! Regex.IsMatch(address, @"^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+$") ) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed regex validation");
        return;
    }   

    try
    {
        var mailAddress = new MailAddress(address);


        Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", mailAddress.Address);
        Console.WriteLine("DisplayName: {0}", mailAddress.DisplayName);
        Console.WriteLine("Host: {0}", mailAddress.Host);
        Console.WriteLine("User: {0}", mailAddress.User);
    }
    catch (FormatException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex);
    }
}
```

And the results:

```
--------------------------------------------
Input: user<test@nomail.com>
Address: test@nomail.com
DisplayName: user
Host: nomail.com
User: test
--------------------------------------------
Input: test@nomail.com
Address: test@nomail.com
DisplayName: 
Host: nomail.com
User: test
--------------------------------------------
Input: Invalid<testnomail.com>
Failed regex validation
--------------------------------------------
Input: Invalid<test@com>
Failed regex validation
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)