# html5 e-mail validation failed

Tags: html, forms

I have this simple input field for e-mail addresses:

```html
<form>
<input type="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

If you write "max@mail.de", you can submit the form, because the email is valid.
If you write "max@.de", you can't submit the form, because the email is invalid.

But!

If you write "max@i9", you can submit the form, too. But the mail is invalid. Why?
And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<form>
<input pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}$" 
type="text" required />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `max@i9` is a valid email as it stated in this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples).
You can "fix" it by adding your own email pattern, see this [tutorial](https://html5-tutorial.net/form-validation/validating-email/):

```
<form>
<input type="email" pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/" required />
</form>
```

Here's a more detailed question about [Why does HTML5 form validation allow emails without a dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573488/why-does-html5-form-validation-allow-emails-without-a-dot)

Comment: The pattern here would still not reference a FQDN. This pattern passes "pallsopp@ge" without the full domain. The following pattern is a modification "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}$" and does require the full domain.

Answer (score 0):

This is because HTML5 type="email" validator is only find @ symbol in your input string. If it is found your form will submitted else it won't submitted.
To avoid this you have to use javaSctipt form Validation like this :-

```js
function validateemail()  
{  
var x=document.myform.email.value;  
var atposition=x.indexOf("@");  
var dotposition=x.lastIndexOf(".");  
if (atposition<1 || dotposition<atposition+2 || dotposition+2>=x.length){  
  alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address \n atpostion:"+atposition+"\n dotposition:"+dotposition);  
  return false;  
  }  
  
}
```

Answer (score -2):

HTML can't help you with data validation, you can learn js to do that