# why checkValidity() is returning "true" for input field of type email with empty value?

Tags: javascript

```js
let email = document.getElementsByClassName("user-input__form-email")[0];

email.type = "email";
console.log("email " + email.value + "  " + email.checkValidity());

if (email.checkValidity() === false) {
  emailError.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Email Address" class="user-input__form-email">
```

For empty value for email input field, isn't checkValidity() should return false value ?

Comment: There's no `required` attribute and therefor an empty string is a "valid" input.

Comment: Make the input required?

Comment: empty string for "email" type is valid ?? Can you please point me to MDN doc for this claim ?

Comment: You might want to think about what "required" means. If something is not required then it can be omitted. And how do you do this with an input field? -> Leave it empty -> empty string.

Comment: I didn't understand your last explanation, pointing me to MDN will be great. As it's source of truth saying "empty string = email address" as well

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#required And a more in-depth information page about the required attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required

Comment: If your (mis)conception would be correct any field with `type="email"` would also be a mandatory field because if it is empty that would be invalid and therefor the form could not be submitted. Which doesn't make any sense... If a field is optional (= no `required` attribute) it can be empty. The content of the `.value` property will be an empty string. It's that easy. How would you make a form with an optional email field? Without forcing the user to manually add it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `checkValidity()` was returning true when empty is because the field was not `required` thus the function thought, because it wasn't required, that empty is valid and it returned true.

I am using `required` in order to not validate an empty input as true.

However, we all know how ugly the stock validation is by default, and you can disable this by adding `novalidate` to your `<form>`

After a few edits and reading your comments, I think this is what you are looking for. A validation that shows your own custom error message if `email.checkValidity()` returns `false`

```js
let email = document.getElementsByClassName("user-input__form-email")[0];
email.type = "email";

function validate_email() {
  if (!email.checkValidity()) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "E-mail is not correct";
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
    return true;
  }
}
console.log("email " + email.value + "  " + email.checkValidity());
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validate_email(this)" novalidate>
  <input placeholder="Email Address" class="user-input__form-email" required>
  <p id="error" style="color: red;"></p>
  <input type="submit" onsubmit="return validate_email(this)">
</form>
```

Comment: strangely for email value "test@test"; checkValidity() is returning true as well. I'm totally confused if this function is working as expected ?

Comment: the checkValidity() checks if the input is ready to be sent by the form, that's why when it wasn't required it was able to send it. type="email" only forces the email field to have an `@` inside the field, I suggest you to check out AJAX validation

Comment: If I use "required" attribute then user is shown default browser error message but in my case I want to show custom error below the input field. Thus I didn't use "required" attribute at first place.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573488/why-does-html5-form-validation-allow-emails-without-a-dot, found answer for 2nd query but for 1st query, I'm not convinced to use "required" attribute. I feel it's a bug in the function itself

Comment: Here you go, this way you can use your own validation on fields @vikramvi

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13975255/2607372

Comment: you asked why it returned true even though it was clearly a false positive. The solution I wrote should get you on your way, or take a look at debugger's answer. I don't know what you mean with that post, but if that works for you that's great, write your own answer and select it as the correct answer so that other people stumbling on your post that are experiencing the same issue can easily find their solution

Comment: Validating an email address is a **highly complex task**; thus the control only implements this very basic check for an `@` character.

Comment: Added some more context, so that people that google: Why `CheckValidity()` returned true on empty field, they will be able to find the solution.

Comment: I'm already missing Java by now :(:(

Comment: I feel that one. But trust me, just give it some time, JavaScript is really easy and fun once you get the hang of it.